# Sailsjs model static method

Tags: typescript, sails.js, definitelytyped

I'm trying to create a type definition for sails.js's Model interface.
sails.js allows you to define a simple file which exports an object with a nested "attributes" object. Each attribute corresponds to a column name in a database, and the column type.

```
//MyModel.js
module.exports = {

  attributes:{
     name:"string"
  }

};
```

To use this model in your code, you write some code like so:

```
MyModel.create({name:"alex"}).then(function(result){
   //the model was inserted into the DB, result is the created record.
});
```

The code I wrote looks like so:

```
declare module Sails{

  export interface Model{
    create(params:Object):Promise<Sails.Model>;
  }
}

class Model implements Sails.Model{

  create(params:Object):Promise<Sails.Model> {
    return undefined;
  }

  attributes:Object;

  constructor(attributes:Object){
    this.attributes = attributes;
  }


}

class MyModel extends Model{
    constructor(attributes:Object){
        super(attributes);
     }
}

var _export = new MyModel({name:string});

export = _export;
```

Here's the problem I'm having. In order for sailsjs to interface with my typescript code properly, `module.exports` has to have that attributes object on it with the database type definitions. This wouldn't be a problem, except when I try to use this class, it needs the static methods like create which aren't on there.

I would like to be able to write my typescript code using the model like so:

```
MyModel.create({name:"bob"}).then((result:MyModel) => {
   //do stuff with result
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it but it isn't pretty:

```
//api/models/MyModel.ts
import Model = require('./Model');

var MyModel = new Model({
  name:"string"
});

export = MyModel;


//api/model/Model.ts
class Model {

  attributes:Object;
  constructor(attributes:Object){
    this.attributes = attributes;
  }

}
export = Model;


//api/types/MyModelQuery.ts
//this file maps to the attributes of a query result

declare class ScreenQuery {
  name:string;
}
export = ScreenQuery;


//sails.d.ts

declare module Sails{

  export interface Model{
    create(params:Object):Promise<Sails.QueryResult>;
    attributes:Object;
  }

  export interface QueryResult{

  }

  export interface Controller{

  }

}
```

I'm still working on it, I'll update this once I've got the full implementation done.

Edit: I've created a blog post fully describing the approach i've taken. [Using typescript with sails.js](http://alexclavelle.blogspot.com/2015/03/using-sailsjs-with-typescript.html)